# Cannot access Database.SetInitializer() using .NET Core 3.0 with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

I want my database to created each time a model changes, which I should be able to achieve using something like:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext {
    public MyContext() {
         Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyContext>()); 
    }
}
```

However, in my .NET Core 3.0 project, `Database.SetInitializer()` is not available:

[image]

How can I use `Database.SetInitializer()` from my project? I haven't had other issues with Entity Framework until now.

Comment: You seem to use EF Core - not EF 6.x. In EF Core you seed data with `HasData`: `protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) { modelBuilder.Entity<Store>().HasData(new Store()); }`

Comment: @JohnyL - Will that also delete the old database and create a new one?

Comment: No, of course - it's just inserting new data.

Comment: @JohnyL - but I want to re-create the database each time the application is run in debug mode. The code in my post shows how to do that in EF 6.x - can’t I do the same thing in EF Core?